# Download the PDF generated by window.print()

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-generation

Is there any JS solution to download the PDF generated by `window.print()` ? I need not to open the print window, but simply download the PDF.

I have tried other plugins but the PDF generated by `window.print()` is the exact thing I needed. 
Any ideas how to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

i think window.print() function gives pop-up to print your html page..noting more, one alternative solution is you can use **jsPDF** library to generate pdf.

https://parall.ax/products/jspdf

Comment: I am Using jsPDF.But it has issues with tables/CSS.

Comment: Ok, you have to try this : html2canvas.js and TableExport.js?

Answer (score 0):

`window.print()` invokes the print dialog or printing process of the browser. Depending on the device, it either physically print a paper or write the output to a PDF printer.

Both these actions happen in the client side and the printout or the PDF is already with the client as of the end of printing.

There is nothing to be "downloaded" as a result of this.

-

And to select the PDF printer directly without seeing the print dialog, mostly a user action is needed. JS has no method to replace this user action.

--

There are some libraries which can turn your web page in to a PDF and let you download it. But none of them are as perfect as the browser default printing.

There are some server side solutions available. Those can generate the PDF with 99.9% perfection and send the result to the front end for you to downlaod.

Please see DOMPDF

Comment: "But none of them are as perfect as the browser default printing." ... assuming of course you consider the print preview of the browser to be the definition by which you judge.

Comment: @KevinBrown No. I judge by the resulted PDF only.

Comment: The point is that the browser is no point for print. It has no concept of "pages" in the sense of a paged media. It provides a false sense of what a page would be like because, for instance, a bootstrap concept of floating content does not take into account that there are "pages" to be dealt with where floats cannot exist on multiple pages in the same place ... or multiple columns of flowing content where a browser again knows nothing of pages so what happens when the page changes. There are many things not considered when you hit "print" in terms of a true print engine and treating content.

Comment: It is the responsibility of the content to tell the browser how to display on the screen as well as how to print on the paper. If it does, the browser knows exactly what to do.

Comment: Good luck with that concept. That would be a winner. A browser is not capable of understanding some of these basic concepts so its impossible for the content to tell it what to do. Example: demonstrate to me how to tell the browser to print in a differnet page layout if my content is one page long or if it is three pages long,

Comment: `@media print {
    footer {page-break-after: always;}
}`

You can apply this depending on the length of the content if you know little JS

Comment: RIght. No answer because that is not the answer. Simplified to a browser person I can see how you think it is. Different margins, different header, different footer and different background for Page 1 and completely different for a document that is two pages and different of 3 or more please.

Comment: That is not the answer. That is the root where you can elicit your answer from.

Comment: Correct, The browser will print what it shows you on a screen. A screen is not a printer nor is it in any way a substitute for the understanding of pagination or paged media. You like what you have on the screen? Hit print screen. You want paged media and print concepts, don;t use the browser as a composition substitute.

Comment: No. Browser will not print what it show on the screen. It will use media rules to decide how to render contents on different devices. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries